# How can the servlet determine when an upload has been cancelled?

Tags: java, javascript, servlets

Here is some code on the javascript side for form-based uploads:

```
iframe.setAttribute('src', 'javascript:false;');
```

I'm using the code above to cancel an in-progress upload associated with an input element placed in an iframe.

I'm using the code below to cancel an in-progress upload sent via XHR:

```
myxhr.abort();
```

In both cases, no more bytes are sent to the servlet.  The part I'm struggling with is on the servlet side.  Currently, I can't figure out a way for the servlet instance to determine if the user has cancelled the upload.  This is critical, otherwise the servlet will go on and process the partially uploaded file as if it is valid.

How can I determine, via the HttpServletRequest, if a user has cancelled the upload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The POST request with the data contains the `Content-Length` header which tells you the size of the data that is going to be uploaded.

So when the data stops coming to your server and the size of the data received is less than expected - it would mean that the user (or some network glitch) has canceled the upload.

Comment: I should have known that.  Thanks for your answer - it looks like this is just what I need.

Answer (score 1):

If the upload has been cancelled the browser will close the connection, resulting in a an IO exception on the servlet side. For example, in Tomcat it will say "Connection reset by peer" and this is a ClientAbortException. Other servers wrap the IOException differently. Point is just catch the IOException and you should be able to handle it as you wish.

Using content-length is not reliable because the HTTP spec does not require content-length headers for POSTs - or for GETs for the matter. Point is, unless you are sure your javascript XHR sets the header explicitly, this method won't work.

Alternatively you could calculate it yourself and set it to be sure, or even better append your own character stream to the end of a the posted data in the XHR, some unique string of characters, e.g. "jh923k49sk$2#%'. In the servlet, snip off the last 14 characters of the inbound message and check it against the string. If it is the same you know they didn't cancel.

Comment: I've found that the IOException doesn't seem to reliably occur.  On Jetty, I always seem to run into an EofException in this case, but not on Tomcat.  In my case, it looks like Content-Length is set for each request, so that may be the best way for me to handle this.  I like your other suggestion though it is not usable when submitting via an input element.

Comment: Not necessarily so; simply have a hidden form field with your unique string and make it the last element in the form. Every browser I've tried (note just the ones I tried, so some might not) seems to order the form fields in the POST in the same order they are in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you can tell, just because a request stream has ended, whether it's done or cancelled.  There would have to be a separate HTTP request to indicate cancellation that would have to include some token or ID associated with the upload, since HTTP is stateless and idempotent.